# scope value not assigning during ionicView.loaded event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to assign a value to input type from controller. Precisely,I am trying to do during ionicView.loaded event and before hiding splashscreen manually.

**Here, it is not working and the value user.ph_no is not getting assigned.**

Also to check, I put a button click event and I am assigning value to user.ph_no inside it.

**It is working.**

What i am missing to get the value assigned during ionicView.loaded event?

Below is my controller with button click event and ionicview onload event.

```
angular.module('app.controllers', ['ionic'])

.controller('registerCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {};
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.loaded', function() {
        ionic.Platform.ready( function() {
            if(navigator && navigator.splashscreen){
                $scope.user.ph_no = "12344434";
                navigator.splashscreen.hide();
            }

        });
    });

    //Button click event
    $scope.Register = function() {
    //$scope.user.ph_no = window.MainActivity.getPhn_number();
    $scope.user.ph_no = "9959";
    };
})
```

Comment: try `$ionicView.afterEnter` instead?

Comment: no luck. tried with 
$scope.$on('$ionicView.afterEnter', function() {
ionic.Platform.ready( function() {

Answer (score 0):

Assign a value to input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="user.ph_no" name="ph_no"  />

.controller('registerCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.user = {
      ph_no:'12344434'
    }
})
```